# delete item in an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

First I make two arrays with players and two arrays with their weapons. Then i would like to make a loop where people gets "killed" and remove them from the temporary ($team1 and $team2) array.

Inside the loop it picks a random player from each loop and compares a reaction value and the player with the highest kills the other. It looks like it only runs once, because there is only one line of who kills who in $this->roundevent and the text of who won the round with the score.

```
function fightRound() {
    unset($this->roundevent);
    $team1 = array($this->t1p1, $this->t1p2, $this->t1p3, $this->t1p4, $this->t1p5);
    $team1wepaons = array($this->t1p1weap, $this->t1p2weap, $this->t1p3weap, $this->t1p4weap, $this->t1p5weap);
    $team2 = array($this->t2p1, $this->t2p2, $this->t2p3, $this->t2p4, $this->t2p5);
    $team2wepaons = array($this->t2p1weap, $this->t2p2weap, $this->t2p3weap, $this->t2p4weap, $this->t2p5weap);


    $alive = true;
    while ($alive) {        

        /* get random team1 player */
        $randomt1 = rand(1, count($team1));

        /* get random team2 player */
        $randomt2 = rand(1, count($team2));


        if ($randomt1 == 1) {
            $playerteam1 = $team1[0];
            $playerteam1w = $team1wepaons[0];
        } else if ($randomt1 == 2) {
            $playerteam1 = $team1[1];
            $playerteam1w = $team1wepaons[1];
        } else if ($randomt1 == 3) {
            $playerteam1 = $team1[2];
            $playerteam1w = $team1wepaons[2];
        } else if ($randomt1 == 4) {
            $playerteam1 = $team1[3];
            $playerteam1w = $team1wepaons[3];
        } else if ($randomt1 == 5) {
            $playerteam1 = $team1[4];
            $playerteam1w = $team1wepaons[4];
        }

        if ($randomt2 == 1) {
            $playerteam2 = $team2[0];
            $playerteam2w = $team2wepaons[0];
        } else if ($randomt2 == 2) {
            $playerteam2 = $team2[1];
            $playerteam2w = $team2wepaons[1];
        } else if ($randomt2 == 3) {
            $playerteam2 = $team2[2];
            $playerteam2w = $team2wepaons[2];
        } else if ($randomt2 == 4) {
            $playerteam2 = $team2[3];
            $playerteam2w = $team2wepaons[3];
        } else if ($randomt2 == 5) {
            $playerteam2 = $team2[4];
            $playerteam2w = $team2wepaons[4];
        }

        if ($playerteam1[reaction] > $playerteam2[reaction]) {
            $this->roundevent .= $playerteam1[id]." kills ".$playerteam2[id]." with ".$playerteam1w;
            $team2 = array_diff($team2, array([$playerteam2]));
        } else if ($playerteam1[reaction] < $playerteam2[reaction]) {
            $this->roundevent .= $playerteam2[id]." kills ".$playerteam1[id]." with ".$playerteam2w;
            $team1 = array_diff($team1, array([$playerteam1]));
        } else if ($playerteam1[reaction] == $playerteam2[reaction]) {
            $whodies = rand(1,2);
            if ($whodies == 1) {
                $this->roundevent .= $playerteam1[id]." kills ".$playerteam2[id]." with ".$playerteam1w;
                $team1 = array_diff($team1, array([$playerteam1]));
            } else {
                $this->roundevent .= $playerteam2[id]." kills ".$playerteam1[id]." with ".$playerteam2w;
                $team2 = array_diff($team2, array([$playerteam2]));
            }
        }


        $this->roundevent .= " <br> ";

        /* check if all players in a team is dead */
        if (empty($team1)) {
            $this->t2score = $this->t2score + 1;
            $this->roundevent .= " <br> Team 2 scores - ".$this->t2score;
            $alive = false;
        } else if (empty($team2)) {
            $this->t1score = $this->t1score + 1;
            $this->roundevent .= " <br> Team 1 scores - ".$this->t1score;
            $alive = false;
        }

    }
```

I have tried many different functions to remove a value from the array, but cant seem to figure out whats going on here. (Also i have noticed that i should use the array_rand() function to choose player instead)

Comment: I unset the $this->roundevent because it should be cleared for every time i call this function.

Comment: No, he means use unset() to delete the item you want to remove

Comment: Btw, you can remove the two big if statements if you do just a bit of math. `$playerteam1 = $team1[$randomt1 - 1];` and so on

Comment: so this means I could use unset($team1[$playerteam1]); ?

Comment: yes, but couldnt it be done in a smart way with array_rand()? :)

Comment: Probably it can, but I´d stick to the method I showed ya. It would shrink the 'selection' part to around 4 lines of code instead of all those if/elses

Comment: when i try to use the unset($team2[$playerteam2]); method i get Warning: Illegal offset type in unset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125212/discussion-between-kingfox-and-manuel-mannhardt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to remove an element from an Array

**unset(ARRAY)**

$myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

```
unset($myArray[1]);
```

output:

```
Array (
  [0] => a
  [1] => c
)
```

**array_splice(ARRAY, OFFSET, LENGTH)**

```
array_splice($myArray, 1, 1);
```

or you can use **`array_diff()`**, if you know the values of the array.

```
$newArray = array_diff($myArray, ["a", "c"]);
```

See for more about [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: yes. but I really need to delete the item in the array by object and not the array id, because of the game logic

Comment: well then array_diff()  is what you need.

Comment: See my update please.

Comment: okay, so instead of deleting the value i want gone, I'm forced to remember the original array values to put inside the new array?

Comment: array_diff is comparing 2 arrays and returns a new array that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: yes, it should remove the difference from the two arrays. Thats why i dont get why this $team2 = array_diff($team2, array([$playerteam2])); isnt working.

Comment: It wont work because `array([$playerteam2]))` means `array( array ( $playerteam2 ) );` You can use array($playerteam2) or [$playerteam2]